# I want to push a line of html text to this notifications list with out the user having to refresh the page

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, updatepanel, push

Cannot phrase correct term or language that I want, so finding hard to search.

Q: From server side, push line of text to user.

Building MVC 4 (asp.net - c# .net4) application. One page will have a "notifications" coloumn which will be a list of new tasks the user should do.
The tasks stored in a database.

When a new task has been added to the database, I want to push a line of html text to this notifications list with out the user having to refresh the page.

Is this possible, or do I need to have the user client side run on timer to request update of notifications?

thanks,
Please point me to similer questions or resources and the obiouse resource that Im looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at a timer unfortunately if you need to support a wide range of browsers but you can use web sockets to push the information on clients that have the support.   Check the website http://www.websocket.org/

Here is a basic tutorial on web sockets:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Comment: Yeah - after searching ajax push - nothing such as this exists, as HTML on its own, or as much as possible, is client controlled. Which for security purposes makes sense. Timer will make for better user interface, as can prevent every second new message coming through, but a more here is a bluk, read it, then another bulk. Thanks.